# Javascript: Re-arranging divs on a screen using drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I currently have 6 square blocks called *'tile'* on my screen inside a div container, something like this:

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="tile1" class="tile"> </div>
    <div id="tile2" class="tile"> </div>
    <div id="tile3" class="tile"> </div>
    <div id="tile4" class="tile"> </div>
    <div id="tile5" class="tile"> </div>
    <div id="tile6" class="tile"> </div>
</div>
```

Each square is 100px by 100px and floats left, to appear in 2 rows of 3. Each square contains it's tile number inside e.g. tile1 -> 1, tile2 -> 2.

I want to be able to drag and re-arrange these tiles.

For example,

If I drag tile 6 to position 1, tile 6 appears in position 1 and the other tiles are pushed along:

tile6 -> pos1

tile1 -> pos2

tile2 -> pos3

tile3 -> pos4

tile4 -> pos5

tile5 -> pos6

Comment: Do some research - for example jqueryui has [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) / [droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) plugins that will give you what you need plus all the issues you will stumble in to down the road but can't see yet..

Comment: Another possible solution is [Dragula](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/)

Comment: thanks guys, is there a way for this to work without jQuery?

Comment: Anyone know how to get this working on iOS, so it uses touch rather than a click and drag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI Sortable plugin. it hase same exact functionality. See this demo page.

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

*Select display as grid example from right menu.

Comment: thanks, this is what I want. Is there a way to get this running without jQuery though?

Comment: This is a jQuery lib so you need to use it.